# How to use server database?

Tags: android, sql-server, remote-server

I made one database in sqlserver. Now I want to connect this server databse to my android application.so I can access it from any where in the world.How can I connect them and how can I access server-databse?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255984/connecting-android-with-ms-sql-server-2008

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Json or XML format(REST API's)  web service`  in order to INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,READ data between your phone and sqlserver.  see [this](https://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/connection-between-php-server-and-android-client-using-http-and-json/) article for more info

and see this post for: [how to connect sql server using JTDS driver in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631758/how-to-connect-sql-server-using-jtds-driver-in-android)