# Class not found exception with com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: mysql, class, ubuntu, jdbc

This is my first post and I hoping I can reach out to the group.
I'm pulling my hair out with this problem.

I'm running a EC2 Ubuntu micro instance with LAMP.
I'm using Java with JDBC to access the mysql database.

The issue is that the Java code keeps throwing a "ClassNotFound" Exception when I execute:
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

I have installed the following:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
sudo apt-get install libmysql-java
```

My imports in the Java file are:

```
import java.text.CharacterIterator;
import java.text.StringCharacterIterator;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.net.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
```

My $CLASSPATH shows:

```
.:/usr/share/java/mysql.jar:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar:/usr/share/java/mysql.jar:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar:/usr/share/java/mysql-5.1.10.jar:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.10.jar
```

In /usr/share/java I have:

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root   4096 2012-05-25 02:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 316 root root  12288 2012-05-24 21:21 ..
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root 448964 2009-11-23 22:38 gnome-java-bridge.jar
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root   2621 2010-03-05 04:16 libintl.jar
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     31 2012-05-25 02:01 mysql-5.1.10.jar -> mysql-connector-java-5.1.10.jar
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root 754057 2010-01-26 08:02 mysql-connector-java-5.1.10.jar
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     31 2012-05-25 02:01 mysql-connector-java.jar -> mysql-connector-java-5.1.10.jar
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     16 2012-05-25 02:01 mysql.jar -> mysql-5.1.10.jar
```

This is the code that always throws up the exception message to an output file:

```
try {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");     
        outyyy.write("Class loaded \n");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        outyyy.write("Class not found! \n");
        outyyy.write(e.getMessage() + " \n");
    }
                    
    this._connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, this._user, this._pass);
    this._isConnected = true;
}
catch (Exception e) {
    this._isConnected = false;
}
```

I'm not sure if it's relevant but I can access and query the database just fine using PHP.

Comment: what does the `e.getMessage()` return?

Comment: Which version of libmysql-java did you install? You may run `dpkg-query -l libmysql-java` to find out.

Comment: What is the commandline used to start the Java program?

Comment: [Tried this one,
hope this will help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631758/how-to-connect-sql-server-using-jtds-driver-in-android/13512108#13512108)!

Answer (score 0):

Set classpath

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar
```

Source: http://marksman.wordpress.com/2009/03/01/setting-up-mysqljdbc-driver-on-ubuntu/