# class not found exception org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver

Tags: jdbc

well, there are so many threads discussed about this topic , but unfortunately nothing worked for me .

I am sending `username/pwd` to the server and server is interacting with `JDBC client` . this is my goal .

but I am getting above mentioned error while executing the below piece of code

ERROR: `Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();`

CLASSPATH varaible here :
       `C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin;C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\db\lib;C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\db\lib\derbyclient.jar`;

I'm pretty sure this jar contains `ClientDriver.class` .
I dont know where I did mistake .. anyone pls help me .

Comment: Tried this one,

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631758/how-to-connect-sql-server-using-jtds-driver-in-android/13512108#13512108] see here[/link]

Answer (score 0):

The `CLASSPATH` environment variable is almost never used. Make sure the 'derbyclient.jar' is on the actual classpath of your application.

- If running from the IDE: make sure it is on the IDE build path of your application
- If running with `java -jar ...` make sure it is in the `Class-path` attribute of the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`
- If running with `java -cp ...` make sure it is in the `-cp` list.

Also if you are using a JDBC 4 compliant driver, you don't need to call `Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver")`, calling `newInstance()` is never necessary to load the driver (unless you are using Java 1.0 or 1.1 which you aren't).

Answer (score 0):

You must add `derbyclient.jar` to `YourProject\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib`. Not needed to add `derby.jar` to classpath.

It's helped me.