# Android Connect To Azure Database

Tags: android, azure, azure-sql-database

I am attempting to connect my android application to my azure hosted database. I have the correctly formated connection string as denoted in azure database documentation.

```
jdbc:sqlserver://Server:1433;database=XXXX;user=XXXX;password={your_password_here};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
```

I have replicated the behavior I am trying to put in my mobile app in a netbeans project by utilizing the MSSQL JDBC driver driver here :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

I attempted to drag this JAR file into my android project but it was throwing multiple dexing errors.

My question is, should I be able to use this JAR in my project and add it to my gradle or is there a different implementation I need to add?

Comment: Please read: [JDBC vs Web Service for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15853367/295004)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202540/android-studio-cant-connect-to-database-in-azure-sql-server